# Unable to add events after AJAX load using jQuery

Tags: ajax, dom, jquery, dynamic-rebinding

I have a web page on which I use jQuery's AJAX to load new elements into a div. This part of my page works fine.

I now want to add a similar event to these newly-added elements. To do this I planned to use jQuery's .live() method but nothing appears to happen.

So I initially start with this

```
<div id="change-agent-list" class="tooltip">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Into .middle I asynchronously load markup that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="main" method="post" action="/ils/agent-selector/" id="main">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTQ1MTc3ODM4NGRkg9mLyLiGNVcP/ppO9C/IbwpxdwI=" />
        </div>
        <ul id="content_0_agentsUL">
            <li>
                <a href="/agent-details/?ag={BF505982-DF16-4D09-BFE4-2ADDCADCC8E4}" class="agent-name link">Agent 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/agent-details/?ag={42F1AE01-59F4-43DE-98C7-A1F99DB3A33C}" class="agent-name link">Agent 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/agent-details/?ag={B3139686-12DA-44A1-A597-E05E1DD08007}" class="agent-name link">Agent 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="agent-details"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page initially loads I use this script - my intention is to add a click handler for each of the *.agent-name* elements that are asynchronously added later.

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j(".agent-name").live("click", function() {
        var agentDetails = $j(".agent-details");
        var loadingContent = '<div id="ajax-load"><img src="/sitecore/__/_images/global/ajax-load.gif" alt="AJAX content loading" /></div>';

       agentDetails.show();

        agentDetails.empty().html(loadingContent);
        var modalURL = $j(".agent-name").attr("href");
        agentDetails.load(modalURL);*/

        return false;
    });
});
```

The problem is that no events are being bound to the *.agent-name* elements. I've tried replacing all the inner script with a simple *alert()* so that I can see if any events are being bound to the *.agent-name* elements, and I can't get this *alert()* to display.

So in other words, no events are being bound to my *.agent-name* elements.

Even if I move the *agent-name* class to the list elements and change the jQuery to simply

```
$j(".agent-name").live("click", function() {
    alert('1');
});
```

I still get nothing when I click on the elements.

Can anyone explain why, or how I fix this so that I *can* late-bind events to elements created in an AJAX callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by using jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of "live".

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `#agent-name` because IDs are unique. You can just use `$('#agents .link')` since you already have a class on each anchor.

Comment: Of course, that was a typo when I was editing for this post. My actual webpage has them as classes, and I've now edited the above post to show this correctly.

Comment: I've edited the original post to show the complete markup that's returned from the AJAX .load() request.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful, but this works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".agent-name").live("click", function() {
            alert("click");
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="main" method="post" action="/ils/agent-selector/" id="main">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTQ1MTc3ODM4NGRkg9mLyLiGNVcP/ppO9C/IbwpxdwI=" />
        </div>
        <ul id="content_0_agentsUL">
            <li>
                <a href="/agent-details/?ag={BF505982-DF16-4D09-BFE4-2ADDCADCC8E4}" class="agent-name link">Agent 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/agent-details/?ag={42F1AE01-59F4-43DE-98C7-A1F99DB3A33C}" class="agent-name link">Agent 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/agent-details/?ag={B3139686-12DA-44A1-A597-E05E1DD08007}" class="agent-name link">Agent 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="agent-details"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```